# Why does Gnome use the order-by triangle the opposite way as Windows does?

Tags: linux, gnome

I included this screenshot for clarity:

[image]

The triangle is (according to my logic) wrongly rotated. Is this a bug, or an intentional choice?

Comment: For me it is natural (it is an arrow!)... I have used GNOME/GTK for last few years though :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's [intentional](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/controls-lists.html.en#controls-lists-sortable). The value increases as you go down the list.